# Using Multiple Times Child Component in Parent Comp with different API calls - All instances rendering same output

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a parent component and a same child component is used multiple times on the parent with different @Input values. Based on this input values i am making a different http call's to display in each instance. But it is not happening that way, it always displays the same output for all instances. Below is my code.

***parent-comp***

```
<div>
<div> Test Parent </div>
 <child-comp [inp1]= 'x', [inp2]=""></child-comp>
 <div> some text </div>
 <div> some text 2 </div> 
 <child-comp [inp1]= '', [inp2]="y"></child-comp>
</div>
```

****child-comp.ts *****

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.childCompService.firstInstance$
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$),
        mergeMap((resp) => {
          return this.performKeys(resp)
            .pipe(mapTo(resp));
        }),
        tap((resp) => {
          this.innerHtml = resp;
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
```

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {

      if (changes['inp1']) {
        this.childCompService.getResults(this.inp1);

      } else if (changes['inp2']) {

        this.childCompService.getData(this.inp2).pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$),
        mergeMap((result) => {
          return this.performKeys(result)
            .pipe(mapTo(result));
        }),
        tap((result) => {
          this.innerHtml = result;
        })
      ).subscribe();
      } else {}
  }
```

****child-comp.html****
****<div [innerHtml] = "innerHtml">***

```
****child-service.ts****

        _firstInstance = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
        firstInstance$ = this._firstInstance.asObservable();
        
        getResults(inp1) {
            req.param = inp1;
            this.http
              .get(url, req)
              .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
              .subscribe((res: any) => {
                this._firstInstance.next(res);
              });
          }
    
    getData(inp2): Observable<string> {
            this.http
              .get(url, req)
              .pipe(
                tap((value) => {
                 return of(value)
                }),
                shareReplay(1)
              );
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NgOnChanges` won't work here, instead use `@Input` with set. In Child component you can do this:

```
public dataFromInput1: any;
public dataFromInput2: any;

@Input() set inp1 (value) {
     // here request the service for input1
     //this.dataFromInput1 = `data form API`
}

@Input() set inp2 (value) {
     // here request the service for input2
     //this.dataFromInput2 = `data form API`
}
```

Note: If you call or update data multiple times try to create new instance of the data received from the API so that angular can detect changes (this is only applicable if the data doesn't update).

Comment: thank you. When you say create new instance of data, you mean i should not use same variable for final html output ?
Also is it still ok to use mergeMap etc when using @Input set?

Comment: Yes you can do that, but create a separate function for such computation. If you use `mergeMap` there will be new instance always. Same Instance meaning updating the value of same object.

Comment: Does the above answer help?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I haven't got chance to try this. I am going to try this week and update here on the latest. Also a QQ, what if instead of multiple input params, if we have one input param of type object(one key value of object to trigger first apicall and other key value change to trigger second api call . Do you think still the same setter solution works. I am going to try that today.

Comment: Yes, it will work. Based on the valuer in the setter you can make the calls.